# How to arrange the bars of the "fill" variable in ggplot together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, categorical-data

This is my code:

```
sur %>% 
  select(circumstances_bite, circumstances_bite_broad) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=fct_infreq(circumstances_bite), fill = circumstances_bite_broad))+
  geom_bar()+
  xlab("No of people")+
  ylab("circumstance of bite")+
  ggtitle ("circumstance of bite by a pet dog")
```

How do I group the bars according to the fill variable? Groping the different colour bars together and not seperately. Both the variables are factors.

[image: my graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to compute the counts manually outside of ggplot, then order you data in your desired order, i.e. by `circumstances_bite_broad` and fix the order via `forecast::fct_inorder`.

Using some fake random example data:

```
set.seed(123)

library(tidyverse)

sur <- data.frame(
  circumstances_bite = sample(LETTERS[1:26], 100, replace = TRUE)
) |>
  mutate(circumstances_bite_broad = case_when(
    circumstances_bite %in% LETTERS[1:9] ~ "a",
    circumstances_bite %in% LETTERS[10:18] ~ "b",
    circumstances_bite %in% LETTERS[19:26] ~ "c"
  ))

sur %>%
  select(circumstances_bite, circumstances_bite_broad) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  count(circumstances_bite, circumstances_bite_broad) |>
  arrange(circumstances_bite_broad, desc(n)) |>
  mutate(circumstances_bite = fct_inorder(circumstances_bite)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = n, y = circumstances_bite, fill = circumstances_bite_broad)) +
  geom_col() +
  xlab("No of people") +
  ylab("circumstance of bite") +
  ggtitle("circumstance of bite by a pet dog")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is absolutely what I needed. Thumbs up for the response.

I have a followup question. Is there a way to set demarcation lines between the graphs of fill variables a, b and c? Just to show them as separate categorise so that it will be easier fo the reader to read?

Comment: The simplest option I can think of would be to use facetting. Try `+ facet_wrap(~circumstances_bite_broad, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") + theme(strip.text.x = element_blank())`

Comment: Yes, this absolutely works.

One more question, in the graph above, if you wish to facet_wrap using a third categorical variable for example "species", is that possible? The two variables "bite_circumstances" and "bite_circumstances_broad" remains the same, but multiple plots similar to the one above is made based on the variable "species". Is that possible?

Comment: Hm. The general answer is yes. But it probably depends on the specific setup. When adding a third variable you have to take care of that in the `count` and the `arrange` step, i.e. add `species` to both. And check whether this works. If not I would suggest to simply ask a new question. At least you now know how to create an example dataset. (: